# What means by 'clear the update region' when painting the client area on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, wm-paint

Here the [Painting the Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/painting-the-window) mentioned that:

> After you finish painting the client area, you clear the update region, which tells the operating system that it does not need to send another WM_PAINT message until something changes.

One may write these code:

```cpp
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            RECT rect;
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
            HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(127, 127, 127));

            FillRect(hdc, &rect, brush);

            const wchar_t * lstr = L"here is information";
            TextOut(hdc,
                5, 5,
                lstr, _tcslen(lstr));


            DrawText(hdc, TEXT("Singleline in center~"), -1, &rect,
                DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);

            MoveToEx(hdc, 50, 100, NULL);
            LineTo(hdc, 44, 10);
            LineTo(hdc, 78, 40);

            Rectangle(hdc, 16, 36, 72, 70);
            Rectangle(hdc, 34, 50, 54, 70);

            DeleteObject(brush);

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
```

What means by clear here? We do not want what we have drawn to be cleared.

Comment: Read the doc completely: *"After you are done painting, call the EndPaint function. This function clears the update region, which signals to Windows that the window has completed painting itself."*

Answer (score 2):

[`WM_PAINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-paint) messages are generated on demand (see [Paint messages will come in as fast as you let them](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111219-00/?p=8863)). For each window, the system maintains an update region. Clients can mark parts or all of a window's client area as "invalid", calling [`InvalidateRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidaterect) or [`InvalidateRgn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidatergn). Either one adds to the update area, but doesn't immediately trigger a `WM_PAINT` message.

When the system determines that it's time to send a `WM_PAINT` message, it is the client's responsibility to empty the update region when it's done painting so that no additional `WM_PAINT` messages are generated until the update region is non-empty again.

The call to [`BeginPaint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-beginpaint) does that for you, so you don't have to worry about this so long as you use standard `WM_PAINT` handling. If you do have more specific requirements (e.g. when using a Direct2D render target) you would have to manually clear the update region with a call to [`ValidateRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-validaterect) or [`ValidateRgn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-validatergn).